# Class ModelCleanupAddon cannot be found by Eclipse-Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse-Plugin which uses EMF and JET to generate java code automatically. When I run it now I have the following error and I don't know where it comes from:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-12-23 11:38:15.760
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.addons.ModelCleanupAddon' from bundle '216'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.addons.ModelCleanupAddon cannot be found by org.eclipse.ui.ide.application_1.0.501.v20141111-1238
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

I tried to add `org.eclipse.ui.ide` to the MANIFEST.MF file but it didn't help.
Here is my MANIFEST.MF file :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: TestPlugin2
Bundle-SymbolicName: TestPlugin2;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: testplugin2.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252658/rcp-application-cannot-find-modelcleanupaddon-class/34440862, I've posted my observations there.